# WCF Tracing not working in IIS 6.0

Tags: wcf, iis, trace

How do I make tracing work in IIS 6.0 ?, The same works fine with IIS 5.1 but not in IIS 6.0. I have tried giving permissions to ASPNET user and also enabled write permissions in the virtual directory.

Below is the code snippet from web.config

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="c:\log\Traces.svclog"  />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>

 <system.serviceModel>
 <diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that you could try:

- Are you sure that it is the ASPNet user that is being used. Check the identity of the app pool and the impersonate=false
- You may need "modify" not just "write"
- You may need to restart the machine after the rights have changed

Comment: ASPNET is not the user that I should give write permissions. Thanks a lot Shiraz!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the log folder name c:\log\  exists.   If not it does not put any trace files.

Not sure whats the logic behind not creating folders automatically ?